# What is the appropriate usage of the length factor in an L-System?

Tags: procedural-generation, l-systems

I'm just starting out with procedural generation and I've made a program that generates lines using a D0L-systems by following [Paul Bourke's website](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/lsys/). For the first two simple examples it works great, but when I input the rules of the *L-System Leaf*, my results are incorrect as can be seen on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wjSZ.jpg).

Could any of you more experienced people point out where I might be going wrong? I'm pretty sure that I'm misunderstanding something about the usage of the length factor. In my case, `lengthFactor` is a static float, that is set once before the generation starts and is used to multiply/divide line's length in the current drawing state. `lenghFactor` itself won't change during the generation.

I'm using OpenGL for rendering and programming in C++.

Comment: To me it looks like your branches on the main stem should be further apart.

Comment: I've not had enough time to investigate and solve the above mentioned case, but what I found about the Kolam rule on the same website is that there were extra characters in the initial axiom that resulted in bad generation. As you can see in [this image](https://imgur.com/a/DhACs4S), the unnecessary brackets wrapping the entire final generated string altered the turning angle  in a bad way. I'm suspecting that something similar might be going on in the first case.